# Go slice usage of [:]

Tags: go

I'm looking at sha1 related code https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.5:src/crypto/sha1/sha1.go;l=146-152

especially this line `append(in, hash[:]...)`

I'm not sure why `hash[:]...` is used, while `hash...` seems to be sufficient.

Here's one piece of test code https://go.dev/play/p/DaIa0X4KyeD

```
func main() {
    s := make([]int, 2, 10)
    s[0] = 1
    s[1] = 2

    d := []int{88}
    d = append(d, s[:]...) // d = append(d, s...) seems to work the same
    fmt.Printf("d is: (%v)\n", d)
    fmt.Printf("d len is: (%v)\n", len(d))
    fmt.Printf("d cap is: (%v)\n", cap(d))
}
```

So my question is what the point of `[:]` is for slice? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hash` is an array (of type `[Size]byte`), not a slice. `hash[:]` is a slice — equivalent to `hash[0:len(hash)]`. The `...` notation requires a slice, so it's applied to the slice `hash[:]` rather than the array `hash`.